# How can I send data to a specific socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

My problem is that the current solution I have for sending a *specific* socket using the library "ws" with node.js is not good enough.

The reason is because if I connect with multiple tabs to the websocket server with the same userid which is defined on the client-side, it will only refer to the latest connection with the userid specified.

This is my code:

```
// Server libraries and configuration   
var server = require("ws").Server;
var s = new server({ port: 5001});

// An array which I keep all websockets clients
var search = {};

s.on("connection", function(ws, req) {
  ws.on("message", function(message){
    // Here the server process the user information given from the client
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    if(message.type == "userinfo"){
      ws.personName = message.data;
      ws.id = message.id;
      // Defining variable pointing to the unique socket
      search[ws.id] = ws;
      return;
    }
  })
})
```

As you can see, each time a socket with same id connects, it will refer to the latest one.

Example If you did not understand:

1. Client connect to server with ID: 1337
2. search[1337] defined as --> websocket 1
3. A new connection with same ID: 1337
4. search[1337] becomes instead a variable refering to websocket 2 instead

Comment: Obviously it will happen, why are you overriding the socket id? Keep all the socket ids in an array for 1 user.

Comment: Could you elaborate? So you mean that I should make a array for every user id containing the socket connections?

Comment: Yes, I basically use https://socket.io/ which has rooms. So it becomes easier. I never `ws` but this the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets provide a means to create a low-latency network "socket" between a browser and a server.

Note that the client here is the browser, not a tab on a browser.

If you need to manage multiple user sessions between the browser and server, you'll need to write code to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This does however not solve my problem. I am wondering how I can process with the information I gave with your help.

Comment: I'd solve your problem by assigning users to individual documents (as represented by browser tabs) and send that data along with any websocket calls. This would differentiate users per document/tab.